# Calculate the integral of this

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate this integral.

$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{b - a \cos \theta} d\theta$$

where a, b are constant.

This is from a test of electromagnetism, but I don't know how to solve it. Although it can be done by Wolfram, I want to know other techniques which can be useful in such a time-limited test.

Comment: $b-a\cos\theta$ have to be not zero, isn't it?

Comment: $\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$Use the fact that $\d \sin \theta = -\cos \theta \d \theta$ and $\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}$ - then introduce the variable $\xi = \cos \theta$. There may be, however, a more elegant way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Using $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$$I=\int_0^\pi\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{b-a\cos\theta}d\theta=\int_0^\pi\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{b+a\cos\theta}d\theta$$

$$I+I=2b\int_0^\pi\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{b^2-a^2\cos^2\theta}d\theta$$

$$\implies\dfrac{a^2}b\cdot I=\int_0^\pi\dfrac{a^2(1-\cos^2\theta)}{b^2-a^2\cos^2\theta}d\theta=(a^2-b^2)\int_0^\pi\dfrac1{b^2-a^2\cos^2\theta}d\theta+\int_0^\pi d\theta$$

Now set $\tan\theta=u$ in $$\int\dfrac1{b^2-a^2\cos^2\theta}d\theta=\int\dfrac{\sec^2\theta}{b^2(1+\tan^2\theta)-a^2}d\theta$$